# Нужна ли в данном случае запятая? Не подскажете правило?

Tags: пунктуация

*Из кафе донесся страшный, болезненный, несколько секунд мучивший меня своими отзвуками крик.*
Влияет ли как-нибудь наличие перечисления на постановку запятой перед словом *крик*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

О запятой перед словом "крик". Причастный оборот "несколько секунд мучивший меня своими отзвуками" стоит перед определяемым словом "крик" и не име­ет зна­че­ния при­чи­ны или уступ­ки. Такой оборот не отделяется запятой от определяемого слова.

**Из кафе донесся страшный, болезненный, несколько секунд мучивший меня своими отзвуками крик.**

Примеры из ходожественной литературы:

Мы въе­ха­ли в узкую, уже потем­нев­шую ули­цу, зарос­шую вёт­ла­ми (В. Вересаев).

В сере­дине апре­ля два гусе­нич­ных трак­то­ра пово­лок­ли сквозь тай­гу довер­ху гру­жен­ные вся­кой вся­чи­ной, тяже­лые, сра­бо­тан­ные из лист­вен­нич­ных бре­вен сан­ные при­це­пы на новое место (П. Проскурин).

Answer (score 1):

Запятая в вашем примере нужна, т. к. определения оторваны от опрделяемого слова.
Правило такого.

Определительный оборот выделяется запятыми, если он отделен от определяемого слова другими членами предложения:

**Наклонившиеся по ветру,** мимо двинулись серые подорожные сорняки (Леон.); Где-то за сотни верст, **отгороженная кручами сосен и широкими тополями непроходимых прибалтийских болот,** раскинулась их большая Родина... (Вороб.); **Полное огня и таинств,** вспыхивало со всех сторон небо (Бун.); Рожденный пустыней, колеблется звук (Забол.); В соседней маленькой комнате на диване, **укрытый больничным халатом,** лежал в глубоком сне мастер (Булг.); Захрустела галька под ногами, **тусклым светом напоминавшая скинутую шкурку змеи** (Леон.); Колесо тряслось и прыгало на капоте в такт ее мыслям, **серое от грязи (Уст.)**

[См.: Академический справочник под редакцией Лопатина. Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации.](http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=118#pp118)

Comment: Серж, вопрос о запятой перед словом *крик*. О каких оторваных  определениях  Вы говорите?

Comment: Страшный, болезненый - определения к слову крик. Они оторваны оборотом " несколько секунд мучивший меня своими отзвуками" .

Comment: Из кафе донеся страшный, болезненный крик, несколько секунд мучивший меня своими отзвуками.

Comment: "Запятая в вашем примере нужна" - это Вы о запятой перед словом *крик*?

Comment: Да, именно о ней.

Comment: И эта запятая, стоящая перед словом "крик", по-Вашему, отделяет определения "страшный, болезненый"? Извините, у меня возникает когнитивный диссонанс. Как может запятая отделять нечто стоящее на расстоянии 6 слов от нее?

Comment: Вы читали правило? Если определения отдалены от определяемого слова, ставится запятая.

Comment: Пожалуйста, сформулируйте ясно: где согласно правилу ставится запятая?, назовите определения, назовите определяемое слово, покажите в каком месте стоит запятая.

Comment: Прочитайте внимательно мой ответ.

Comment: Серж, где здесь отделение определительного оборота от определяемого слова другими членами предложения? Это из другой оперы, и к данному примеру отношения не имеет.

Comment: Серж, так как  я понимаю Ваш ответ, он ошибочен. Я предложил разобраться, для этого проговорить все детали.Но Вы почему-то не захотели...

Comment: – М_Г , я же объяснил: определения "страшный, болезненный" отделены причастным оборотом.

Comment: По правилу выделяется запятыми то, что отделено от определяемого слова, а не то, чем оно отделено!